# Paypal is not accepting all credit cards- Sandbox and with real

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented donate button which is really working fine, but there is one issue which was reported by few donas.

They are not able to donate it using their credit card.  They are seeing Error

```
"Something went wrong" 
We couldn't process this donation, Please try again later. this could  just be temporary glitch.
```

But few donors are able to make payments using their credit cards.

I have used few test credit card and out of one worked.

****1) 4111111111111111 -  Didn't worked**

**2) 4012888888881881 - Worked**

**3) 4222222222222 - Didn't worked****

Any idea, why all credit cards not worked

Comment: "*this could  just be temporary glitch.*" Are you *sure* this is the exact error text PayPal sent you? I would be very surprised if they had an error message with this exact text.

Comment: yes, it's from paypal. and its on paypal website itself. if this is temporary glitch. how come my second credit card worked on the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Those card numbers are not accepted by the PayPal sandbox. Use a [random one from developer.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2FcreditCardGenerator%2F)

For better results when testing, use a [Personal sandbox account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) , it is faster for testing than entering a card manually, and less likely to result in an unexpected decline.

As for any declines of real cards in the live environment, that would be an unrelated issue; likely a problem with that particular card.

Comment: What should be unrelated  issue.  there is no such error showing

Comment: Use random cards in sandbox. Use real cards in the live environment. If real cards are declined in the live environment, it's unrelated to the non-random cards you were using in sandbox.

Comment: Real cards are declined in live environment and getting this error "We couldn't process this donation, Please try again later. this could  just be temporary glitch."

Comment: As mentioned, this is unrelated to problems with testing in sandbox with non-random numbers. Contact PayPal if you have questions about declines in the live environment.